# Handling Cascading Many to Many EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I am not sure how to properly setup my tables so I don't get an error like this when trying to do many to many.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_TableB_TableA_TableBId' on table 'TableB' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.'
```

My models

```
public class TableA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TableB> TableBs { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TableCId { get; set; }
    public virtual TableC TableC { get; set; }
    public int TableAId { get; set; }
    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }
}

 public class TableAConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TableA>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TableA> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
    }
}

 public class TableBConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TableB>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TableB> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}

//code snippet

//remove all tableB
  company.TableBs.Clear();


// add all new dealers.
foreach (var d in dto.Data)
{
    company.TableBs.Add(new TableB() { TableCId = d.id, TableA = TableA });
}

   dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

edit

```
 public class TableC
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TableBs> TableBs { get; set; }

}

    public class TableCConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TableC>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TableC> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.Code).HasMaxLength(5).IsRequired();

    }
}
```

Comment: Read.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete And if that doesn't help, post the complete model and a minimal repro.  There's not enough there to know what's going on.

Comment: `TableA` and `TableB` as shown have no multiple cascade paths. There must be something common to `TableB` and `TableC` which is causing it.

Comment: Ok, I added TableC, unless it is one of the other relationships I stripped out. I am just showing the many-to-many not any of the other relationships that TableA and TableC are part of.

Comment: It should be in `TableA` and `TableC` relationships you stripped out. The exception is showing the place where the problem is *detected*, which doesn't mean it's the place causing it. It usually happens when `TableA` and `TableC` have FK relationship to something common, like `User` or something.

Comment: Ok, seems like they are sharring a common table. so how should I to help it figure it out? I guessing I have to tell it the cascade direction or something?

Comment: If you can't avoid the cycle, at least you should break the cascade by turning cascade delete off for at least on of the involved relationships. And handle deletion manually or via trigger.

Comment: I guess I going to have to turn it off. I am not sure if this the right way of doing it.             builder.HasOne(x => x.TableA).WithMany(x => x.TableB).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict); and I did this in the TableBConfig